# Likelihood loss function for finite support probability distribution in Neural Networks

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution, probability-generating-fn

I have managed to reproduce solution from this [article](https://medium.com/hal24k-techblog/a-guide-to-generating-probability-distributions-with-neural-networks-ffc4efacd6a4) and made it work for my dataset.

Instead of making a Neural Network output a scalar (regression), we make it output two parameters of a probability distribution.

This is done by changing the last layer of existing MLP architecture to layer of two nodes, and after that we use negative-log likelihood loss of [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). For each output parameters we get, we can generate probability density function (pdf) and if needed, get the $y$ prediction by calculating the median of the given pdf.

This is the loss function formula from the article.

$$\mathcal{L}(n, p \mid Y)=\frac{\Gamma(Y+n)}{\Gamma(Y+1) \Gamma(n)} p^{n}(1-p)^{Y}$$

After we apply $-\log (L(n, p \mid Y)))$ we get:

$$\begin{aligned} \mathrm{NLL}(n, p \mid Y)=& \log \Gamma(n)+\log \Gamma(Y+1)-\log \Gamma(Y+n) \\ &-n \log (p)-Y \log (1-p) \end{aligned}$$

My problem is that negative binomial distribution is supported on semi-infinite intervals $[0, \infty]$, this makes my network sometimes output a pdf which goes out of target bounds. What I need is distribution which has finite supported intervals.

Which one should I use? What would you recommend if my target in the dataset is discrete and in range of $[a, b]$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}_0$. What is the loss function of the probability distribution you recommend?